# How to get average and standard deviation of grouped data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, stdev

I'm trying to work with a database using Google Sheets.

I am able to access the database using the importJson script from here:https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON

using the query: `=importJson("https://mywebsite.com/json-data");`

It populates my Google Sheets just fine like this mockup:

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| Age | Weight | Country |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 10  | 120    | US      |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 10  | 140    | US      |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 10  | 160    | US      |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 11  | 180    | CA      |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 12  | 190    | GBR     |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 12  | 200    | GBR     |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

I'd like to be able to show the data grouped by age, with an average weight for that age, standard deviation for the weights in that age, like so...

```
+-----+----------------+----------+
| Age | Average weight | Std. Dev |
+-----+----------------+----------+
| 10  | 140            | 20       |
+-----+----------------+----------+
| 11  | 180            | 0        |
+-----+----------------+----------+
| 12  | 195            | 5        |
+-----+----------------+----------+
```

I've tried to play around with creating a pivot table in sheets, but I can't figure out how to get the average of all values for each age in a column or the std deviation.

When I try to add a column with weight values by average, I get a `DIV/0` error.

Is this doable in Sheets?

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: 0]

paste in **E2** cell:

```
=QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select A,avg(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label avg(B)''", 0)
```

paste in **G2** cell and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(STDEV(FILTER(B:B, A:A=E2)), 0)
```

paste in **H2** cell and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(STDEVP(FILTER(B:B, A:A=E2)), 0)
```

---

## UPDATE:

STDEV and STDEVP are now supported under array processing

```
=BYROW(E2:E4, LAMBDA(xx, IFERROR(STDEV(FILTER(B:B, A:A=xx)), 0)))
```

[image]

all-in-one formula solution:

```
={QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select A,avg(B) where A is not null 
  group by A label avg(B)''", 0), 
 BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), 
 LAMBDA(xx, IFERROR(STDEV(  FILTER(B:B, A:A=xx)), 0))), 
 BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), 
 LAMBDA(xx, IFERROR(STDEV.P(FILTER(B:B, A:A=xx)), 0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, once I copied the imported JSON data to a different sheet and pasted as "values", then converted formatting to "numbers". Thank you for the assistance! Is there a way to directly import the JSON as numbers? I think that is where the calculations originally failed.

Comment: try wrapping it into `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE( i-json-fx-here ), i-json-fx-here ))`

Comment: Awesome! Wrapping in `arrayformula` did the trick. I guess importing JSON directly is not the same as getting formatted numeric data? I will have to learn a bit more about the arrayformula method then! Thank you.